# NimbleCSV : Elixir

Tags: csv, erlang, elixir

I'm trying to use **NimbleCSV** library for a personal project but I'm having some problems...

```
NimbleCSV.define(MyParser, separator: ",", escape: "\"")

defmodule Siren do
  def parseCSV do
    IO.puts("Let's parse CSV file!")
    File.stream!("name.csv")
  |> MyParser.parse_stream
  |> Stream.map(fn [name, team, position, height, weight, age] ->
    %{name: name, team: team, position: position, height: String.to_integer(height), weight: String.to_integer(weight), age: String.to_integer(age)}
    end)
  |> Enum.map(&IO.puts(&1))
  end
end
```

Like you can see above I'm using Stream, but when I launch my Mix task it's crashed :

```
➜  siren mix siren
Compiling 1 file (.ex)
Let's parse CSV file!
** (NimbleCSV.ParseError) unexpected escape character " in " \"Team\", \"Position\", \"Height(inches)\", \"Weight(lbs)\", \"Age\"\n"
    deps/nimble_csv/lib/nimble_csv.ex:427: MyParser.separator/5
    deps/nimble_csv/lib/nimble_csv.ex:360: anonymous fn/4 in MyParser.parse_stream/2
    (elixir 1.10.3) lib/stream.ex:902: Stream.do_transform_user/6
    (elixir 1.10.3) lib/stream.ex:1609: Enumerable.Stream.do_each/4
    (elixir 1.10.3) lib/enum.ex:3383: Enum.map/2
    (mix 1.10.3) lib/mix/task.ex:330: Mix.Task.run_task/3
    (mix 1.10.3) lib/mix/cli.ex:82: Mix.CLI.run_task/2
```

Here my CSV file:

```
"Name", "Team", "Position", "Height(inches)", "Weight(lbs)", "Age"
"Adam Donachie", "BAL", "Catcher", 74, 180, 22.99
"Paul Bako", "BAL", "Catcher", 74, 215, 34.69
"Ramon Hernandez", "BAL", "Catcher", 72, 210, 30.78
"Kevin Millar", "BAL", "First Baseman", 72, 210, 35.43
"Chris Gomez", "BAL", "First Baseman", 73, 188, 35.71
"Brian Roberts", "BAL", "Second Baseman", 69, 176, 29.39
"Miguel Tejada", "BAL", "Shortstop", 69, 209, 30.77
"Melvin Mora", "BAL", "Third Baseman", 71, 200, 35.07
"Aubrey Huff", "BAL", "Third Baseman", 76, 231, 30.19
"Adam Stern", "BAL", "Outfielder", 71, 180, 27.05
"Jeff Fiorentino", "BAL", "Outfielder", 73, 188, 23.88
"Freddie Bynum", "BAL", "Outfielder", 73, 180, 26.96
"Nick Markakis", "BAL", "Outfielder", 74, 185, 23.29
"Brandon Fahey", "BAL", "Outfielder", 74, 160, 26.11
"Corey Patterson", "BAL", "Outfielder", 69, 180, 27.55
```

The problem must come from my escape character that I defined before but I don't understand why ? What is an escape character here ? For me is the double quotes surrounding each string in CSV's rows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*CSV* states for *Comma-Separated Values* and it’s the format that has its own RFC4180. One cannot put spaces whenever they want to. Change the input to the one shown below and everything would work fine. The issue is *spaces after commas*, or, put it in other words, escape character not immediately follow the delimiter.

```
"Name","Team","Position","Height(inches)","Weight(lbs)","Age"
"Adam Donachie","BAL","Catcher",74,180,22.99
"Paul Bako","BAL","Catcher",74,215,34.69
"Ramon Hernandez","BAL","Catcher",72,210,30.78
"Kevin Millar","BAL","First Baseman",72,210,35.43
"Chris Gomez","BAL","First Baseman",73,188,35.71
"Brian Roberts","BAL","Second Baseman",69,176,29.39
"Miguel Tejada","BAL","Shortstop",69,209,30.77
"Melvin Mora","BAL","Third Baseman",71,200,35.07
"Aubrey Huff","BAL","Third Baseman",76,231,30.19
"Adam Stern","BAL","Outfielder",71,180,27.05
"Jeff Fiorentino","BAL","Outfielder",73,188,23.88
"Freddie Bynum","BAL","Outfielder",73,180,26.96
"Nick Markakis","BAL","Outfielder",74,185,23.29
"Brandon Fahey","BAL","Outfielder",74,160,26.11
"Corey Patterson","BAL","Outfielder",69,180,27.55
```

---

*NimbleCSV* comes with a default implementation, [`NimbleCSV.RFC4180`](https://hexdocs.pm/nimble_csv/NimbleCSV.RFC4180.html#content)
and it is exactly what you use, so you don’t need yo define your own parser, use the default one.

```rb
defmodule Siren do
  def parseCSV do
    IO.puts("Let's parse CSV file!")

    File.stream!("name.csv")
    |> NimbleCSV.RFC4180.parse_stream()
    |> Stream.map(fn [name, team, position, height, weight, age] ->
      %{name: name, team: team, position: position,
        height: String.to_integer(height),
        weight: String.to_integer(weight),
        age: String.to_float(age) # NOTE float here!
      }
    end)
    |> Enum.to_list()
    |> IO.inspect()
  end
end
#⇒ [
#  %{
#    age: 22.99,
#    height: 74,
#    name: "Adam Donachie",
#    position: "Catcher",
#    team: "BAL",
#    weight: 180
#  },
#  ...
# ]
```

Comment: Hi and thanks Aleksei Matiushkin. For the float comment I have a question : when my age is 30 or even 30.00 it doesn't work. Indeed 30 is an integer but it doesn't work anyway... Why ?

Comment: CSV File:
```"Name","Team","Position","Height(inches)","Weight(lbs)","Age"
"RamonHernandez","BAL","Catcher",72,210,30```


**Error message (just beginning):**
** (ArgumentError) argument error
    :erlang.binary_to_float("30")
    lib/siren.ex:13: anonymous fn/1 in Siren.parseCSV/0
    (elixir 1.10.3) lib/stream.ex:572: anonymous fn/4 in Stream.map/2
    (elixir 1.10.3) lib/enum.ex:3686: Enumerable.List.reduce/3
    (elixir 1.10.3) lib/stream.ex:931: Stream.do_list_transform/7
    (elixir 1.10.3) lib/stream.ex:1609: Enumerable.Stream.do_each/4

Comment: To get float out of integer, multiply it by 1.0, they are different types.

Comment: But I must multiply if is an integer and before Stream.map I think because the error becomes here. How in Elixir can we implement with ease this action-condition ? Because I stock nowhere my data in an Elixir object, don't I ?

Comment: I am not sure I follow. You control the data. If you expect both `"30"` and `"30.0"` to come, use [`Float.parse/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Float.html?#parse/1) as `age |> Float.parse() |> elem(0)`.